# How to output a link in an input field via a prompt?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prompt

I am struggling with this and can't get it to work. I am using jQuery to click on a link that will open me a prompt. In this prompt, I want the user to add a URL to link it to some other websites. That works fine, but I can't get the value of the prompt to be shown properly in the input field.

> The error I am getting after adding my text in the prompt is the fact
>   that it outputs it like [Object object].

I do know how to do this in *plain JS*, but not in jQuery and I need `jQuery`.

This is my code:

```
    $(".html-button").on("click", function () {
    var urls = prompt("Add a link", "http://");
    var setText = $("#post-text").val().append('<a href="'+ urls + '"</a>'); 
// Adding prompt text into my input field
    $("#post-text").val(setText);
                            });
```

I thought I could do this by using `append` instead of `innerHTML`, which I would use in plain JS... Can someone help please?

**PS:** preferably I would not want to output the anchor already in my input field, but only after submitting the post, but this is a nice to have.

Edit: [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/g0hnrx6a/1/)

Comment: could this work? `$("#post-text").val( $("#post-text").val() + '<a href="'+ person + '"</a>');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have mixed up some variables here. You are assigning the value of the prompt response to var **urls**, but then expecting it to be in an undefined var **person** (guessing you've used the example for this from the W3 Schools Tutorial (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp)).

Assuming that your input element has an id of **post-text** - then you would do this:

```
$("#post-text").val(urls);
```

I am working on the assumption here that you're writing the URL into an input field, as you suggest. If you want those a tags in the input field as well then it would be:

```
 $("#post-text").val('<a href="' + urls + '"</a>');
```

If your intention is to output it as a link somewhere including the HTML 'a' tags so it can be clicked, then you'd need to append it to an appropriate element (not a input field) in the right place in the DOM/on the page.

Lastly, if you want to write the value into the field after the form as been submitted (for whatever reason) you could either store it in a variable and write it on submit, or perhaps in a hidden field. I am unsure why you would want to do this though.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting the same error. Yes, I used person and mixed it up there, but error remains the same. The output is: [Object object] after adding my text in the prompt...

Comment: Could you create a JSFiddle showing an example of what you've done? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Of course. Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/g0hnrx6a/1/ and to your question: I meant a link description with that. So only showing the link description in the input field, but after submitting, showing the link itself. But as I said, it's a nice to have.

Comment: I saw what I did wrong, but still getting a plain text as a output, while it's an anchor. Can we do something like a link description?

Comment: You're setting the return value of the jQuery selector to the text there. Which I guess is what you just realised? So you want the textarea to include the A tags and such?

Comment: var setText = $("#post-text").val('<a href="' + urls + '">' + urls + '</a>');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194231/discussion-between-vinih-and-siyah).

Comment: Here is a little example giving you an idea of the sort of things you could do to provide the user experience you are looking for - obviously you would replace writing the data to a link on the screen with writing to a hidden field or some such. Make sure you do not introduce any XSS or other vulnerability by properly sanitising the user input.  https://jsfiddle.net/xkombteg/